# determine jpeg filesize without actually saving the jpeg

Tags: c#, image-processing, image-manipulation, jpeg

I have an image in PNG or BMP format. I would like to find out the filesize of that image after compressing it to a jpeg **without saving the jpeg**.

Up to now I did it the following way:

```
frameNormal.Save("temp.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
tempFile = new FileInfo("temp.jpg");
filesizeJPG = tempFile.Length;
```

But because of the slow disk access, the program takes too long.
Is there a way to calculate the filesize of the newly created jpeg? Like converting the PNG in memory and read the size...

Any help is very much appreciated :-)

Comment: Can you paste frame normal's Save method, We can then get the length of the stream that the method will use to write the file to disk

Comment: @@lupedito , please mark the answer as such by clicking the check-mark under the voting buttons

Answer (score 7):

You can write the image data to a `Stream` instead of supplying a filename:

```
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    frameNormal.Save(mem, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    filesizeJPG = mem.Length;
}
```

Comment: Right answer, i would like to add that for the sake of performance, it can be usefull to write a FakeStream to which you can write but only logs the amount of bytes written

Answer (score 3):

You can to something like this:

```
MemoryStream tmpMs = new MemoryStream();
frameNormal.Save(tmpMs, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
long fileSize = tmpMs.Length;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try loading it into memory without saving to disk.  Look up [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx).

Also, this answer might help:  [How to get the file size of a "System.Drawing.Image"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221345/how-to-get-the-file-size-of-a-system-drawing-image)