# ASP.Net MVC 3: Get length in kb of an WebImage

Tags: asp.net, image, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, avatar

I have a small form that allow user to upload an avatar
I used WebImage to get the file uploaded from client (WebImage.GetImageFromRequest() that return WebImage object), in the server i have to check to size of avatar, how can i do that?

**Edit: I mean the length of it, the length in kb**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage(v=vs.99).aspx

The WebImage class has properties that expose the Height and Width of the image in pixels. So this will give you the size of the image.

**EDIT**

I think this post might help you with that, but it requires you have the image saved to disk.

[How to get the file size of a "System.Drawing.Image"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221345/how-to-get-the-file-size-of-a-system-drawing-image)

Additionally, you could do something like this, though it'll have some overhead as you'll be putting all of the bytes into memory...

```
WebImage uploadedImage = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest("somefile");
long sizeInKBytes = uploadedImage.GetBytes().Length / 1024;
```

Comment: so sorry, my bad E, i mean the length of it, the length in kb