# Image size in MB from pixel height and pizel width

Tags: c#, wpf

maybe a stupid question, but:
how do you calculate the size of an image in mega bytes when you know the images
pixel height and pixel width?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want before or after file compression?

Comment: Pretty sure Google can answer that pretty quickly. EDIT: yep, here's a [byte per pixel chart](http://www.scantips.com/basics1d.html), found in less than 5 seconds

Comment: Look into [how-to-get-the-file-size-of-a-system-drawing-image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221345/how-to-get-the-file-size-of-a-system-drawing-image)

@Ilya Ryzhenkov makes it very simple.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221345/how-to-get-the-file-size-of-a-system-drawing-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on color depth.  If you were using 8-bit pixels, it would be:

`height * width / 1048576`

If you were using 32-bit pixels, it would be:

`4*height*width/1048576` which is `height*width/262144`

Comment: Also depends on the stride, whether the image is in memory or a file format, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is the calculation I use to get the size of a raw bitmap image:

```
// Calculate the pixel depth in bytes:
int pixSize = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(myImage.PixelFormat) / 8;
int size = (myImage.Height * myImage.Width * pixSize) / 1048576;
```

This is only the size for the raw bitmap.  As Scott Jones mentions, this does not account for the stride (padding in the buffer's bytes) or image formats that compress.  It is only a minimum size for a raw bitmap.